# way to migrate a table form one db to other db on different servers automatically?

Tags: database, postgresql, e-commerce

I have a system that has users membership and uses postgresql, now I am working on another mini ecommerce application that will use the same user credentials used on postgresql user application. when a new user signs up on postgresql user app, data from postgres to ecommerce site will get updated automatically.

> Please Note: will be using 2 different databases for two different
>   applications but same user table on both apps. there will be no sign
>   up or registrations on ecommerce app.
>   Original (main db) surely is postgresql 8.4 but other one could be mysql or similar postgresql haven't really decided yet as the ecommerce app could be in php whereas main app is in grails(java)

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the other database?

Comment: So, both DBs are going to be postgresql?  Correct?  If so, what are their versions?

Comment: I have added information to my note in the question. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The first and obvoius solution is to use [dblink](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/dblink.html) assuming both servers are postgres.

However you can write your own *partial replication daemon*. Below there is a simple example of replication of table *users* into SQlite database.

We have table *users* in postgres *usersdb* database:

```
create table users (
    id serial primary key,
    name text);
```

Create log table for *users*:

```
create table users_log (
    id serial primary key,
    action text);
```

Create trigger on table *users*:

```
create or replace function users_trigger ()
returns trigger language plpgsql as $$
declare
    newaction text;
begin
    if (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') then
        newaction:= 'update users set 
        name = '''||new.name||''' where id = '||old.id::text;
    elsif (TG_OP = 'INSERT') then
        newaction:= 'insert into users values 
        ('||new.id::text||', '''||new.name||''')';
    elsif (TG_OP = 'DELETE') then
        newaction:= 'delete from users where id = '||old.id::text;
    end if;
    insert into users_log (action) values (newaction);
    return null;
end; $$;

create trigger users_trigger
  after insert or update or delete
  on users
  for each row
  execute procedure users_trigger();
```

Create SQlite3 database *users.db* and table *users* in it:

```
create table users (
    id integer primary key,
    name text);
```

Daemon script checks users_log every 2 seconds. If there are new actions then script makes them one by one in SQlite database and deletes from users_log:

```
<?php
$postgres = new PDO('pgsql:host=localhost port=5432 dbname=usersdb');
$sqlite = new PDO('sqlite:users.db'); 

$sql = 'select * from users_log order by id limit 1';
while (true) {
    sleep(2);
    while ($row = $postgres->query($sql)->fetch()) {
        $sqlite->query($row[1]);
        echo $row[1]. "\n";
        $postgres->query("delete from users_log where id = $row[0]");
    }
}
?>
```

For simplicity the script is absolutely minimalist and should be fitted out with necessary exception handling.

Comment: Just a quick comment.  This should work and is similar to what I have done for pulling modified data from one "master" database to an "application-purposed" copy of the data.  While not a solution for the OP because he is on PostgreSQL 8.4, I feel like my solution is a bit more robust because it is based on the audit trigger solution here. http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger_91plus.  For other future readers, this allows for use of the hstore so that you can easily see what fields have changed for your "update" statements or to see if you even care about the change.